# iOS 8 Beta Keychain User Access Control

Tags: keychain, ios8, touch-id

I am looking at the new user access control abilities with the introduction of Touch ID when accessing keychain.

Here's the scenario...

- I have written a user secret to the keychain with the new access control object in the Keychain query.
- Next time I attempt to return this secret, I will be presented with the Touch ID / Passcode interface as expected.
- Next time I attempt to write the same data to the keychain, I want to first check if it already exists.
- This also presents the Touch ID interface even if i specify the return data attribute to false. But this is not what I want.

Is this the expected behaviour or am I missing a specific attribute to disable the Touch ID interface?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is possible by doing something similar to:

```
// --- Add this code to your save method

// Adds a new keychain item
let status: OSStatus = SecItemAdd(keychainQuery as CFDictionaryRef, nil)

if status == errSecSuccess {
    println("Keychain Add: \(KeychainResultCode(rawValue: status)?.description)")
    return true
} else if status == errSecDuplicateItem {
    // perform an update
    return self.update(key, data: data)
} else {
    return false
}
```

Does the above works for your needs?